# Sequelize included column not recognized in where clause

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have included a column in my query called 'FullName' in the Customer model its a CONCAT of the FirstName and the LastName.

```js
const salesEntities = await Sale.findAll({
             subQuery: false,
             include: [{
                 model: Product,
                 where: {
                     RepresentativeId: representativeId
                 },
             }, {
                 model: Warranty,
                 where: warrantyWhereStatements
             },
             {
                 model: Customer,
                 attributes: {
                     include: [[sequelize.fn("CONCAT", sequelize.col("Customer.FirstName",), sequelize.col("Customer.LastName")), "FullName"]],
                 }
             }
             ],
             order: orderOptions,
             where: saleWhereStatements,
             limit: 4,
             offset: page * 4 - 4
         });
```

And when I try to use it in a where clause like

```js
{ '$Customer.FullName$': search },
```

It's giving this error: Unknown column 'Customer.FullName' in 'where clause'
Any suggestions how can I use this column in where clauses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to use the column in the WHERE clause.

Sequelize will create an SQL query from the parameters you used, and because the FullName column doesn't exist in the table it cannot be used in an SQL query.

Comment: @StoianDardzhikov Yes, search for the first and last names separately. Or combine first and last name into a single column.

Comment: But the only way to search on a combined column is if a use a sequelize.literal which makes the code vunerable to SQL injections.